# Breaking values of multiple of 20 (20,40,60,80...) into candles of 20 (Stocks)

Tags: python, python-3.x, charts, logic, stock

I have the following logic which reads data from a stock exchange file and builds an Excel data table or a chart.

I'm building a graphic like the following:
[image]

As you can see in the image, I have this green candle which varied at once 50 points.
In my logic, I managed to create a `multipleTimes`, which calculates if this unusual behavior happens.

What I need to do is break this 50 candle in 2 candles of 20, and the 10 points remaining will be ignored.
So for example,

1. If I have a variation of 60, it will break into 3 candles of 20.
2. If I have a variation of 75, it will break into 3 candles of 20 and ignore the 15 points.

Making it look like this (23, 24):

[image]

The file is like this, which refers to stock trade winz23, the last columns are the tick columns, which vary from 5 to 5 points, but in some cases, it can vary 50, 70, or more points at once, which causes my error (https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f70a02c57b8c93a9009b4cb5a6b53c6220231120222005/1f909e):

```
WINZ23|2023-10-25 09:00:58|115240
WINZ23|2023-10-25 09:00:58|115240
WINZ23|2023-10-25 09:00:58|115290
WINZ23|2023-10-25 09:00:58|115290
WINZ23|2023-10-25 09:00:58|115275
WINZ23|2023-10-25 09:00:58|115275
WINZ23|2023-10-25 09:00:58|115250
WINZ23|2023-10-25 09:00:58|115250
```

```
# import socket, base64
import re
import sys
import xlsxwriter
from operator import neg
from datetime import datetime

# Todas as interações
MAPPED = []
CANDLES_ERROR = []
CANDLES_ACERTO = []
CANDLE_PAST_MAPPED = []

FIRST = True
GET_FIRST_TICK = True
RESET = True
READ_INPUT = True

# Logica
INDEX = 1
CLOSE = 0 
CLOSE_REDUZIDO = 0
OPEN = 0
MAXIMO = 0
MINIMO = sys.maxsize
SINALIZADOR = ''
RANGE = 0
CANDLE_TICK_FIX = 0
CANDLE_VALOR_FIX = 0

# Dado passado logica
MAXIMO_PASSADO = 0
MINIMO_PASSADO = 0
ABERTURA_PASSADO = 0
CLOSE_PASSADO = 0         

# Excel
# file_to_open = './example.txt'
file_to_open = './TickByTick/2023-10-25.txt'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('new2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('firstSheet')

# Analytics
ANALYTICS_SINALIZADOR = ''

class Box():
    def __init__(self, index, horario, close, abertura, close_one, maximo, minimo, high_one, low_one, open_one, close_reduzido, range, analytics):
        self.index = index
        self.horario = horario
        self.close = close
        self.abertura = abertura
        self.close_one = close_one
        self.maximo = maximo
        self.minimo = minimo
        self.high_one = high_one
        self.low_one = low_one
        self.open_one = open_one
        self.close_reduzido = close_reduzido
        self.range = range
        self.analytics = analytics

class CandleBox():
    def __init__(self, asset, index, close, abertura, maximo, minimo):
        self.asset = asset
        self.index = index        
        self.close = close
        self.abertura = abertura
        self.maximo = maximo        
        self.minimo = minimo        

def maximo_e_minimo():
    global MAXIMO, MINIMO
    if (CLOSE > MAXIMO):
        MAXIMO = CLOSE
    if (CLOSE < MINIMO):
        MINIMO = CLOSE

# Store only finished candles
def add_to_candle_box_map(asset):
    global PAST_MAPPED_DATA
    CANDLE_PAST_MAPPED.append(CandleBox(asset, INDEX, CLOSE, OPEN, MAXIMO, MINIMO))

# Stores all candles
def add_to_map(horario):
    global MAPPED
    MAPPED.append(Box(INDEX, horario, CLOSE, OPEN, CANDLE_PAST_MAPPED[INDEX].close, MAXIMO, MINIMO, CANDLE_PAST_MAPPED[INDEX].maximo, CANDLE_PAST_MAPPED[INDEX].minimo, CANDLE_PAST_MAPPED[INDEX].abertura, CLOSE_REDUZIDO, RANGE, ANALYTICS_SINALIZADOR))    

def reset_data_after_box_create():
    global RANGE, INDEX, MAXIMO, MINIMO

    RANGE = 0
    INDEX += 1              
    MAXIMO = 0
    MINIMO = sys.maxsize

def count_multiples_of_20(end):
    count = 0
    for value in range(1, end + 1):
        if value % 20 == 0:
            count += 1
    return count

def create_candle(asset):
    global OPEN, CLOSE, CANDLE_TICK_FIX

    # Calculo do maximo e minimo
    maximo_e_minimo()       

    if OPEN != 0 and CLOSE >= (OPEN + 20):                   
        add_to_map(asset)           
        add_to_candle_box_map(asset)          
        reset_data_after_box_create()    
        OPEN = CLOSE                                                  
    elif OPEN != 0 and CLOSE <= (OPEN - 20):            
        add_to_map(asset)              
        add_to_candle_box_map(asset)            
        reset_data_after_box_create()      
        OPEN = CLOSE       
    else:                                          
        add_to_map(asset)    

def handle_box(asset, valor):     
    global CLOSE, CLOSE_REDUZIDO, FIRST, OPEN, RESET, FIRST, ANALYTICS_SINALIZADOR, CANDLE_TICK_FIX, CANDLE_VALOR_FIX

    CLOSE_REDUZIDO = valor - OPEN

    multipleTimes = count_multiples_of_20(abs(CLOSE_REDUZIDO))

    # IF CLOSE_REDUZIDO IS multiple
    # 40 -> create 2 candles
    # 60 -> create 3 candles
    # 80 -> create 4 candles 

    #some logic here
    if multipleTimes > 1 and INDEX > 1:
        for x

    if abs(CLOSE_REDUZIDO) > 20 and INDEX > 1:        
        if CLOSE_REDUZIDO < -20:                
            CANDLE_TICK_FIX = (abs(CLOSE_REDUZIDO) - 20)                                                                 
        elif CLOSE_REDUZIDO > 20:                                
            CANDLE_TICK_FIX = (abs(CLOSE_REDUZIDO) - 20)                                                  
    
    CLOSE = valor + CANDLE_TICK_FIX

    # Seta como primeira vez que roda
    if FIRST == True:
        OPEN = CLOSE           
        FIRST = False
        add_to_candle_box_map(asset)
        add_to_candle_box_map(asset)          

    create_candle(asset)        
    
    CANDLE_TICK_FIX = 0   
    ANALYTICS_SINALIZADOR = '' 
try:    
    with open(file_to_open, 'r') as arquivo:
        # Itere sobre as linhas do arquivo
        for linha in arquivo:
            # Divida a linha em partes usando o caractere '|'
            partes = linha.split('|')            

            # Verifique se a linha tem o formato correto (deve ter 6 partes)
            if len(partes) >= 3:
                # Extraia os valores das partes
                codigo = partes[0]
                data = partes[1]
                valor1 = partes[2]     
     

                handle_box(data, int(valor1))    

                time = datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').time()

                if time == datetime.strptime('9:10:00', '%H:%M:%S').time():
                    raise KeyboardInterrupt
except KeyboardInterrupt:    
    if (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'txt'):         
        print('TXT Wrote')
        with open('candle-25.csv', 'w') as file:    
            for index, line in enumerate(CANDLE_PAST_MAPPED):
                if index == 0:
                    writable = 'Asset,Index,Open,High,Low,Close\n'
                else:
                    writable = f'{line.asset},{line.index},{line.abertura},{line.maximo},{line.minimo},{line.close}\n'                
                file.write(writable)
    else:
        worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Iteração')
        worksheet.write(0, 1, 'Candle')
        worksheet.write(0, 2, 'Horario')
        worksheet.write(0, 3, 'Abertura')
        worksheet.write(0, 4, 'Close')
        worksheet.write(0, 5, 'Close[1]')
        worksheet.write(0, 6, 'High')
        worksheet.write(0, 7, 'Low')
        worksheet.write(0, 8, 'High[1]')
        worksheet.write(0, 9, 'Low[1]')
        worksheet.write(0, 10, 'Open[1]')        
        worksheet.write(0, 11, 'CloseReduzido')        
        worksheet.write(0, 12, 'Range')
        worksheet.write(0, 13, 'Analytics')

        # candles acerto
        worksheet.write(0, 17, 'Candles acerto')
        worksheet.write(1, 17, f'{CANDLES_ACERTO}')

        # candles error
        worksheet.write(2, 17, 'Candles error')
        worksheet.write(3, 17, f'{CANDLES_ERROR}')


        print(f"""
        Tamanho: {INDEX}       
        """)

        for index, entry in enumerate(MAPPED):   
            if entry.close_reduzido >= 20:             
                cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#90EE90'})
            elif entry.close_reduzido <= -20:
                cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE'})
            else:
                cell_format = None
            worksheet.write(index+1, 0, str(index))
            worksheet.write(index+1, 1, entry.index)
            worksheet.write(index+1, 2, entry.horario)
            worksheet.write(index+1, 3, entry.abertura)
            worksheet.write(index+1, 4, entry.close)
            worksheet.write(index+1, 5, entry.close_one)
            worksheet.write(index+1, 6, entry.maximo)
            worksheet.write(index+1, 7, entry.minimo)    
            worksheet.write(index+1, 8, entry.high_one)
            worksheet.write(index+1, 9, entry.low_one)        
            worksheet.write(index+1, 10, entry.open_one)                
            worksheet.write(index+1, 11, entry.close_reduzido, cell_format)                
            worksheet.write(index+1, 12, entry.range)                                  
            worksheet.write(index+1, 13, entry.analytics)                                  

        workbook.close()
except Exception as e:    
    print('Error', e)
```

For the chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import mplfinance as mpf

file = 'candle-25.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file)

data.Asset = pd.to_datetime(data.Asset)
data = data.set_index('Asset')

mpf.plot(data, figratio=(20,12), type='candle', tight_layout=True, title='Candle dia 25', style='yahoo')
```

But as you can see in this excel image, the values from `abertura` does not vary 20 points when it closes.
[image]

This is an example of 4pt graphic in profit:
[image]

Comment: Seems like you are asking someone to help find what is wrong with your algorithm, correct?  How is this algorithm different from Renko ?   It's sounds like you are trying to make a Renko chart with brick size == 20.  If so, there are many places that have already solved this algorithm.

Comment: I don't think so, in Profit, it does not appear as renko, but appears as 4p (20 points), do logic comes from my code. I will update the answer with an example of the chart